# Need regular expression for \ / (backslash, forwardslash)

Tags: java, android, regex

I need a regular expression for "\/" (It is not a V, it is a  backslash and a forwardslash(?))
It is okay to only catch the "\" and replace it with a "" nothing.

Tried:

```
parsed= parsed.replace(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\/"), "");
parsed= parsed.replace("\\", "");
parsed= parsed.replace("\\\", "");
parsed= parsed.replace("\\\\", "");
```

None of them works.
Im little confused.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, didn;t get your question properly? Do you want to replace "\/" with "" ?

Comment: I want to erase all the forward slashes \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. To remove `\/`, use this :

```
parsed= parsed.replaceAll("\\\\/", "");
```

`\\` is a `\` in a java string, and you need to have `\\` to have your escaped `\` in a regex. Hence the `\\\\`.

**EDIT :**

I may have misunderstood. To remove all `/` ,simply use

```
 parsed= parsed.replaceAll("/", "");
```

No need to escape, then, but it's better to use [the correct method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Not working, i got still data like this:
http:\/\/myaddress.com\/test\/pictures\/2.png" . . . . .
I want to get rid of all the forwardslashes

Comment: Sorry, forwardslashes, not the back, my bad.